# Is there a universal converter in Python that turns different files into .txt files?

Tags: python-3.x

I have many different files of different types (XML, txt, .sh, ect). Is there a way for me to convert these files into .txt files in Python?

`files = []
mainList = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(directory):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
for fil in files:
    f1 = open(fil, "r")
    data = f1.readlines()
    mainList.append(data)`

This is what I have so far. It takes all of the paths of the files onto a list.

I would like to append all of the code into one big .txt file for analysis.

Comment: Your snippet should do pretty much what you're after: concatenate all files as text. I'm guessing you're not entirely satisfied with it? If so, how?

Comment: The second for loop doesn't work. I don't know why I put it there. Readlines doesn't let me read non .txt files.